# How to increase left and right margin in each cell of Dash DataTable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using `fill_width=False`, this makes everything in the table visible cramped.

My goal is to add some space to the left and right of the contents in each cell. I am attempting this with the `style_cell` and have tried adding both margin and padding, but neither are changing the table.

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='tbl1',
    columns=[{
        'name': f'{j}',
        'id': f'{j}',
    } for j in datatable_col_names
    ],
    data=[
        {f'{j}': '' for j in datatable_col_names}
        for j in range(2)
    ],
    export_headers='display',
    fill_width=False,
    style_cell={'margin-right': '5px', 'margin-left': '5px'}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to use `padding` instead of `margin`:

```
style_cell={'padding-right': '30px', 
             'padding-left': '30px'
           },
```

However, I recommend using alignment:

```
style_cell={'text-align': 'center'},
```